# React lifecycle animations

Tags: animation, lifecycle, reactjs, unmount

I'm trying to find a way to perform animation depending of the ReactElement's lifecycle, it's pretty easy to do an animation when the component has just been mounted, but I would do another one before the component unmount.

I can't really use the ReactCSSTransitionGroup because that won't use RequestAnimationFrame.

Just to describe a bit my case, my component is a sidebar, that I can toggle on/off depending on some user's inputs.

```
var Sidebar = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        var menuUfeWidth = $('.menu-ufe').width();
        $(this.getDOMNode()).transition({x: menuUfeWidth}, Utils.animationDuration * 2, 'snap');
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className={'leaflet-sidebar left'}>
                <div className={'ufe-content'} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I am wondering how would you work your way off to be able to have an animation before the component unmount.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ReactCSSTransitionGroup` is just a specialized version of `ReactTransitionGroup` that calls `componentWillEnter`, `componentDidEnter`, `componentWillLeave`, and `componentDidLeave` based on your defined CSS.

If you don't want to use CSS animations, you can simply use `ReactTransitionGroup` and use a component that implements [these lifecycle hooks](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup) using RAF-based animations:

```
<ReactTransitionGroup component="div">
  <MyCustomReactTransitionComponent key={...} />
</ReactTransitionGroup>
```

Here's an example I found from another SO post: http://jsbin.com/jebumipimo/1/edit?html,console,output